# Seleccionar elementos de jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Quiero seleccionar n elementos dentro de clase1, pero que si se acaban estos elementos continue por la clase2.

```
<div class="listas>
    <ul class="clase1">
      <li>list item 1</li>
      <li>list item 2</li>
      <li class="third-item">list item 3</li>
      <li>list item 4</li>
      <li>list item 5</li>
    </ul>
    <div>test</div>
    <ul class="clase2">
      <li class="esteNo">list item 1</li>
      <li>list item 2</li>
      <li class="third-item">list item 3</li>
      <li>list item 4</li>
      <li>list item 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>

var numElementosSeleccionar = 7;
$(".listas").on("click", ".clase1", function(){
   var elem =$(this);
   for(var i = 1; i< **Me flata este dato!¿numElementosSeleccionar?**; i++){
    elem=elem.next();
    elem.css("background-color", "yellow");
    //me falta que cuando se acaben los elementos de la clase1 pase a los de la clase2 menos los que tengan la clase "esteNo"
   }

});
```

En este caso si selecciono el primer li me debería poner el bg color en amarillo hasta el tercero li de la clase2

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Tu pregunta no se entiende bien. ¿Quieres que si haces click en un `li` cualquiera empiece a seleccionar hasta `7` elementos `li` hacia abajo, sin contar ese sobre el que hiciste click y sin contar los que tengan la clase `esteNo`? ¿Sólo se deben seleccionar los elementos del tipo `li`?

Comment: @A.Cedano quiero que desde el que hago clic me cuente n elementos, en este caso 7 y si no hay suficientes elementos pase a la siguiente lista la de class2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edito**. He hecho algún cambio. La idea es que la lista sea circular. Si pulsamos en un elemento con clase `.esteNo` no colorea nada. Si pulsamos en uno que no tenga la clase comienza a colorear desde ese elemento hasta el `numElementosSeleccionar`. Si termina con los elementos de la `clase2` empieza por los de la `clase1`

```js
let numElementosSeleccionar = 7;
$(".listas ul li").on("click", function(){   
  //Obtenemos todos los li que no tengan la clase .esteNo
  let lis = $(".listas ul li:not('.esteNo')");
  //Obtenemos el índice del elemento clicado dentro del array lis
  let idx = $.inArray(this,lis);

  //Sólo colorea si pulsamos en un li con clase distinta de .esteNo.
  if(idx!==-1){
    //Mientras haya elementos li por colorear seguimos
    while(numElementosSeleccionar>0){
      //Si llegamos al final de la lista empezamos en el índice cero.
      if(idx>=lis.length){
        idx=0;
      }    
      $(lis[idx]).css("background-color", "yellow");
      idx++;
      numElementosSeleccionar--;
     }   
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="listas">
    <ul class="clase1">
      <li>list item 1</li>
      <li>list item 2</li>
      <li class="third-item">list item 3</li>
      <li>list item 4</li>
      <li>list item 5</li>
    </ul>
    <div>test</div>
    <ul class="clase2">
      <li class="esteNo">list item 1</li>
      <li>list item 2</li>
      <li class="third-item">list item 3</li>
      <li>list item 4</li>
      <li>list item 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Por cierto, tienes una errata en el selector del click, te falta el punto en `listas` (`$(".listas")`)

Comment: interesante :), pero el problema es que siempre empieza por el elemento 1 de la clase1, si le hago clic al elemento 2 de la "clase1" debería empezar a colorear por este